# Почему политики Laravel не работают с гостями?

Tags: php, laravel

Я использую политики laravel для проверки доступа к методам контроллера.

Вот мой контроллер PostController. Метод index() для вывода списка пользователей:

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Post $post)
    {
        $this->authorize($post);
        return $post->all();
    }
}
```

Вот моя политика PostPolicy (проверка прав доступа к методу index() контроллера PostController).

```
class PostPolicy
{
    // This function executes only for authenticated users.
    // I want to use it for guest users too
    public function index(User $user)
    {            
        return $user->can('get-posts');
    }
}
```

Я использую модуль https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust для авторизации по ролям. Роли и привилегии хранятся в базе и я могу использовать вызов `$user->can('get-posts')` для проверки прав на просмотр списка постов. Это работает с аутентифицированными пользователями, но почему-то не работает с гостями. Для гостей вообще не вызывается метод Index в политике PostPolicy. Для гостей доступ к методу index контроллера PostController всегда запрещен.

Почему в Laravel политики не работают с гостями? Ведь у гостей тоже могут быть какие-то права. Как мне назначать права гостям?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что index ожидает на вход объект класса User:

public function index(**User** $user)

А если пользователь не авторизован, то он для него не существует такого объекта. Мне больше всего понравилось такое решение:
Создается класс `Guest extends User` и пишете

```
# Http/Middleware/Authenticate
protected function authenticate(array $guards)
{
  if (empty($guards)) {
      return $this->auth->authenticate();
  }

  foreach ($guards as $guard) {
      if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->check()) {
          return $this->auth->shouldUse($guard);
      }
  }

  $this->auth->setUser(new Guest());
}
```

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/10568#issuecomment-243692377

Соответственно в аргумент пишете

public function index(**Guest** $user)